# Stuck with ForLoop and Inserting DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have this DataFrame:

```
    manufacturer    description
0   toyota          toyota, gmc 10 years old.
1   NaN             gmc, Motor runs and drives good.
2   NaN             Motor old, in pieces.
3   NaN             2 owner 0 rust. Cadillac.
```

And I want to fill the NaN values with keyword taken from the description. To that end I created a list with the keywords I want:

```
keyword = ['gmc', 'toyota', 'cadillac']
```

Finally, I want to loop over each row in the DataFrame. Split the contents from the "description" column in each row and, if that word is also in the "keyword" list, add it in the "manufacturer" column. As an example, it would look like this:

```
    manufacturer    description
0   toyota          toyota, gmc 10 years old.
1   gmc             gmc, Motor runs and drives good.
2   NaN             Motor old, in pieces.
3   cadillac        2 owner 0 rust. Cadillac.
```

Thanks to a friendly person in this community I could improve my code to this:

```
import re
keyword = ['gmc', 'toyota', 'cadillac']
bag_of_words = []
for i, description in enumerate(test3['description']):
bag_of_words = re.findall(r"""[A-Za-z\-]+""", test3["description"][i])
for word in bag_of_words: 
    if word.lower() in keyword:
            test3.loc[i, 'manufacturer'] = word.lower()
```

But I realized that the first row also changed values even though it was not NaN:

```
  manufacturer  description
0   gmc         toyota, gmc 10 years old.
1   gmc         gmc, Motor runs and drives good.
2   NaN         Motor old, in pieces.
3   cadillac    2 owner 0 rust. Cadillac.
```

I would like to only change the NaN values but when I try to add:

```
if word.lower() in keyword and test3.loc[i, 'manufacturer'] == np.nan:
```

It doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix. You did several things wrong:

- Mixing up the index of description and the description itself (solved by `enumerate()`).
- `bag_of_words` should be renewed for each word, not appended.
- Wrong item being iterated (should be `word`, not `bag_of_words`).

Some of the errors can be easily seen if intuitive/conventional names were chosen. Do spend some time on that.

**Code**:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

# test3 = the main dataset
keyword = ['gmc', 'toyota', 'cadillac']

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+')

for i, description in enumerate(test3['description']):
    bag_of_words = tokenizer.tokenize(description.lower())
    for word in bag_of_words:
        if word in keyword:
            test3.loc[i, 'manufacturer'] = word
```

**Output**:

```
test3
Out[31]: 
  manufacturer                       description
0       toyota             toyota, 10 years old.
1          gmc  gmc, Motor runs and drives good.
2          NaN             Motor old, in pieces.
3     cadillac         2 owner 0 rust. Cadillac.
```

### re.findall() over RegexpTokenizer

I personally think `nltk` is a relatively heavy module to be imported, installed and deployed. If only a string split is to be conducted, I'd recommend using `re.findall` to extract the valid word patterns. For example:

```
import re

# won't extract numbers, currency signs and apostrophes
re.findall(r"""[A-Za-z\-]+""", test3["description"][3])

# the output is much cleaner than before
Out[39]: ['owner', 'rust', 'Cadillac']
```

But this is up to the choice of user depending on the entire task.